# How to alter primary key in table for snowflake?

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I created a table with a primary key. I would like to alter a primary key.

I thought using Alter Table command is the solution, but not successful.

`ALTER TABLE "tablename" ALTER PRIMARY KEY (col1,col2);`

Could you please help me how to alter primary key using SQL statement?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can add primary key constraint to a column but cannot alter an existing one.

https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/sql/create-table-constraint.html#out-of-line-unique-primary-foreign-key

Answer (score 8):

Drop and recreate the primary key. Here's an example:

```
ALTER TABLE "tablename" DROP CONSTRAINT "pk_name";
ALTER TABLE "tablename" ADD CONSTRAINT "pk_name" PRIMARY KEY (col1,col2);
```

Answer (score 2):

In case you've multiple primary keys, it's done like this:

```
ALTER TABLE SCHEMA.TABLE DROP PRIMARY KEY;
ALTER TABLE SCHEMA.TABLE ADD CONSTRAINT CONSTRAINT_NAME PRIMARY KEY (col1, col1, ..., coln);
```

Answer (score -2):

I added primary key to the table but when I tried inserting multiple rows with same values against the column on which primary key is defined, it still allowed me.

Comment: The answer does not help. Posts an answer when it provides help. You can use a comment if you need to provide informations