# How do I cast a primary key to BigInt in a table view (snowflake)?

Tags: sql, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I have a source table that has an `int` primary key (call it `entryId`). Sadly, the data producer never updated the schema, and their table exceeded the 2.1b limit for int, causing some primary keys to now be negative,

so the `entryId's` go
`1,2,3,..., 2101262082, 2101262083, -2147483639, -2147483638,...`

I am looking to "fix this" by creating a view on top of this troublesome table. Is there a good way to cast these into BigInts?

I am thinking

```
SELECT 
   CASE
   WHEN entryId < 0 THEN entryId + 2^31
   ELSE entryId
END AS entryId, *
FROM table
```

But not sure if there is a better way.

Comment: I cannot get `^` to run in my snowflake. Does that run for you? The carrot is not supported in mine. You could use abs(entryid) but that may conflict with some other entryids?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to alter primary key in table for snowflake?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62027790/how-to-alter-primary-key-in-table-for-snowflake)

Comment: It doesn't sound like you need to alter the primary key, but rather the data type of the column.  You should be able to alter table...alter column if you are changing the precision of the number to a larger number, but not the scale or a decrease in precision.  Also, a good lesson here is use number(38,0) for all integers in Snowflake.  There is no space or performance hit for allowing the max length of a number for all integers.

Comment: Sorry, I used POWER() in the end; I can't modify the source table, but I'd like to be able to sort in the entryId KEY for general purpose.

Answer (score 1):

[bitshiftleft](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/functions/bitshiftleft.html) is how you do the power/shift

```
select column1 
    ,to_char(column1,'XXXXXXXX') as in_hex
    ,column1 + bitshiftleft(2, 31) as fix
    ,to_char(fix,'XXXXXXXX') as fix_hex
    ,iff(column1>=0, column1, column1 + bitshiftleft(2, 31) ) as res
    ,to_char(res,'XXXXXXXX') as res_hex
from values
(1),
(2),
(127),
(2101262082), 
(2101262083), 
(2147483647),
(-2147483648),
(-2147483639), 
(-2147483638),
(-2),
(-1)
```

| COLUMN1 | IN_HEX | FIX | FIX_HEX | RES | RES_HEX |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | 4,294,967,297 | ######## | 1 | 1 |
| 2 | 2 | 4,294,967,298 | ######## | 2 | 2 |
| 127 | 7F | 4,294,967,423 | ######## | 127 | 7F |
| 2,101,262,082 | 7D3EB702 | 6,396,229,378 | ######## | 2,101,262,082 | 7D3EB702 |
| 2,101,262,083 | 7D3EB703 | 6,396,229,379 | ######## | 2,101,262,083 | 7D3EB703 |
| 2,147,483,647 | 7FFFFFFF | 6,442,450,943 | ######## | 2,147,483,647 | 7FFFFFFF |
| -2,147,483,648 | 80000000 | 2,147,483,648 | 80000000 | 2,147,483,648 | 80000000 |
| -2,147,483,639 | 80000009 | 2,147,483,657 | 80000009 | 2,147,483,657 | 80000009 |
| -2,147,483,638 | 8000000A | 2,147,483,658 | 8000000A | 2,147,483,658 | 8000000A |
| -2 | FFFFFFFE | 4,294,967,294 | FFFFFFFE | 4,294,967,294 | FFFFFFFE |
| -1 | FFFFFFFF | 4,294,967,295 | FFFFFFFF | 4,294,967,295 | FFFFFFFF |